# How to auto create InfoPath Form in SharePoint based on a SharePoint List

Tags: list, document-library, infopath

For example, I have a List called "Student Name" and a InfoPath document library called "Students Forms".

When I have insert all the Student Names into the List 'Student Name', and do a action (* See below), the InfoPath document library 'Students Forms' will populate all the forms using the List.

If I have 3 names inside the List e.g. Jack, Peter and Johnson. After performing a action, I will be able to see Jack.xml, Peter.xml and Johnson.xml inside the InfoPath document library.

**Action**

The action can be like running a console application or pressing a button or so but I am interested in how do one goes about doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I found another way to do this by using the Workflow function - Create New List Item.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using the lists.asmx web service.